# Rails/Grape Rspec undefined method `shopping_element_relations` for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-grape

I want to test a method that update `promo_code` to `used` if `shopping_process` is finalized. Additional it should create a pdf using `ShoppingProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher`

Here is my method which I want to test

```
def finalize_shopping_process(form)
  if finalize_process == true
    shopping_process.campaign_code.update(state: 'used')
    document_creator_class = ShoppingProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher.new(shopping_process).call
    document_creator_class.new(shopping_process).call
  end
  Success(form)
end
```

and the specs:

```
describe 'campain code' do
  subject(:process_update) do
    described_class.new(
      shopping_process: shopping_process,
      form: form,
      finalize_process: true,
    ).call
  end

  it 'updates state of assigned campain code' do
    updated_shopping_process = process_update.value!
    expect(updated_shopping_process.campaign_code.state).to eq('used')
  end
end
```

At the end I've got an error

> NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `shopping_element_relations' for nil:NilClass

The weird thing is that if I remove this lines from the tested method:

```
document_creator_class = ShoppingProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher.new(shopping_process).call
document_creator_class.new(shopping_process).call
```

Specs will pas. I've no clue where I'm wrong.

**Edit:**

all error below:

```
ShoppingProcesses::Update.call campain code updates state of assigned campain code
     Failure/Error: return false unless parent_group.shopping_element_relations.hiding.any?

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `shopping_element_relations' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire stack trace of the error?
I think the error is in `ShoppingProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher`.

Comment: @Surya I think the class itself works well it was tested in a difference place. Maybe I should use instance double to test it somehow?

Comment: If you feel you need not test the functionality of `ShoppingProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher.new(shopping_process).call` their either mock the response or as you have suggested use double.

Comment: Nope, I don't need to test functionality of this class but I don't know how to mock it.

Answer (score 0):

`def finalize_shopping_process(form)
  if finalize_process == true
    shopping_process.campaign_code.update(state: 'used')
    document_creator_class = ShoppingProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher.new(shopping_process).call
    document_creator_class.new(shopping_process).call
  end
  Success(form)
end`

In the above function `document_creator_class` this is initialized to the call method and not the class as intended.
Replace the line

`document_creator_class = ShoppingProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher.new(shopping_process).call` 
with

`document_creator_class = ShoppingProcessDocumentCreatorFetcher`
and then try.

I hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The specs will pass with your changes, unfortunately if I change it in your way the whole functionality behind this method will not worked (the double call is required to get link to the PDF in admin panel)